# Alert boxes in flash 4.7 not working correctly

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a flash project that I originally did in Flash 4.0, but just moved it in to 4.7. Now, all of the alert boxes look weird. They don't look like popups anymore, just text and buttons jammed together at the top of the screen whenever I call the `Alert.Show("text")` method like in this screenshot

[image]

This is a pretty significant problem since this application is using a lot of alert boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer as much as a work around, but changing the theme from "aero" back to the default theme "fixed" the problem. From my experience thus far, this isn't the only bug I've found with the newest version of flash builder.